# C# XmlDocument SelectSingleNode without attribute

Tags: c#, xpath

I need to get xml node which misses specific argument. Let's say I have following c:\temp\a.xml:

```
<files>
  <file product="myproduct">C:\file_myproduct</file>
  <file>C:\file_general</file>
</files>
```

How can I get the C:\file_general value which has no attribute? I tried:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\temp\a.xml");

// C:\file_myproduct - good
string myproduct = doc.SelectSingleNode("/files/file[@product='myproduct']").InnerText;


// I need C:\file_general here, but this gives again the C:\file_myproduct
string general = doc.SelectSingleNode("/files/file").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the not(...) function:

```
string general = doc.SelectSingleNode("/files/file[not(@product)]").InnerText;
```

It is specified [here, in the W3C Recommendation "XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0"](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Boolean-Functions), which is implemented in .NET, System.Xml.XmlDocument.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value