# Powershell/C# XmlDocument selecting only the nodes without attributes

Tags: c#, xml, powershell, xpath

I'm trying to read a Visual Studio project file to select the `<PropertyGroup>` item that has no attributes to extract the value from the `<AssemblyName>` node.  The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57905933/c-sharp-xmldocument-selectsinglenode-without-attribute) is close to what I'm looking for but instead of not having a specific attribute I need it to have no attributes

I've tried the following in Powershell without any success.

```
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new();

$xml.Load("WebApplication4.csproj")
$ns = [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager]::new($xml.NameTable);
$ns.AddNamespace("prj", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003")

$xml.SelectNodes("//prj:PropertyGroup", $ns).Count
```

Is there a way to use `xpath` syntax in the `selectsinglenode` method that would return just the one node that has no attributes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.7\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{7EC4A73B-EA1B-4A6C-B2ED-093E3615C40E}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WebApplication4</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WebApplication4</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it, with just xpath, could be:

```
 $xml.SelectNodes("//prj:PropertyGroup[count(@*)=0]", $ns)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Jack Fleeting's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60235210/45375) shows how to do it properly with XPath alone.

The following alternative shows how to perform the filtering after the fact, in PowerShell code.

---

You need to check the length of the `.Attributes` collection on the target elements to find the one(s) without attributes:

```
$xml.SelectNodes("//prj:PropertyGroup", $ns).Where({ $_.Attributes.Count -eq 0 })
```

Note that [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where) is a PowerShell-supplied array (collection) method that enables filtering of any collection via a script block (`{ ... }`) that needs to return `$true` for each element (`$_`) to be selected.