# XmlDocument SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

On Stack Overflow there is a document explaining the use of XmlDocument and how to select a node.

[C# XmlDocument SelectSingleNode without attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57905933/c-sharp-xmldocument-selectsinglenode-without-attribute)

The code presented is the code I am using as follows.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\FileXml.xml")
string Version = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Version").InnerText;
Console.Write(Version); //I want to see 3
```

The Xml file is shown below "in its entirety".

```
<CharacterObject xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <Version>3</Version>
   <Path>C:\\FilePath\FileName.xml</Path>
</CharacterObject>
```

The error that I am receiving is that SelectSingleNode above returns null. It returned null when I searched for CharacterObject as well. No matter what XML node I search for the function SelectSingleNode returns null. This means I must be using SingleSelectNode incorrectly just not sure how.

I would like SelectSingleNode to return the node so that InnerText will return the Version information in the XML Node. I'm just having a problem in usage of reading the information from the nodes.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], rather than "well reality is more complicated" - it's probably those complications that are causing the issue, but we can't tell because we can only see the simplified version. I'd also personally suggest using LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) rather than `XmlDocument` if you can.

Comment: Additionally, if you're referring to another Stack Overflow question and answer, it would be useful to link to it, so we can explain how you're potentially misinterpreting it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Comment: Updated as requested

Comment: I have solved it. I removed the namespace information from the XML document in an attempt to see if the namespace was an issue as it appears to be an important part of the XmlDocument class and in reading the paths and nodes. Eliminating the xmlns attribute in the root XML node is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement?view=net-6.0) on `XmlDocument.DocumentElement` - it is a root xml element. So in your case it is `CharacterObject` already.
When you call `.SelectSingleNode('/CharacterObject')` for it - you are requesting an `CharacterObject` element inside the root `CharacterObject` - which is not there at all.

You can simply use `XmlDocument.DocumentElement.InnerText` to achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem has a solution. This might be due to the namespace attribute in the XML root node itself. Eliminating this attribute solves my issue.